# Why Thread.sleep is bad to use

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

Apologies for this repeated question but I haven't found any satisfactory answers yet. Most of the question had their own specific use case:
[Java - alternative to thread.sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143719/java-alternative-to-thread-sleep)
[Is there any better or alternative way to skip/avoid using Thread.sleep(1000) in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182223/is-there-any-better-or-alternative-way-to-skip-avoid-using-thread-sleep1000-in)

My question is for the very generic use case. Wait for a condition to complete. Do some operation. Check for a condition. If the condition is not true, wait for some time and again do the same operation.

For e.g. Consider a method that creates a DynamoDB table by calling its createAPI table. DynamoDB table takes some time to become active so that method would call its DescribeTable API to poll for status at regular intervals until some time(let's say 5 mins - deviation due to thread scheduling is acceptable). Returns true if the table becomes active in 5 mins else throws exception.

Here is pseudo code:

```
public void createDynamoDBTable(String name) {
  //call create table API to initiate table creation

  //wait for table to become active
  long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + MAX_WAIT_TIME_FOR_TABLE_CREATE;

  while(System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime) {
    boolean status =  //call DescribeTable API to get status;
    if(status) {
         //status is now true, return
         return
    } else {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10*1000);
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
  }

  throw new RuntimeException("Table still not created");
}
```

I understand that by using `Thread.sleep` blocks the current thread, thereby consuming resources. but in a fairly mid size application, is one thread a big concern?
I read somewhere that use `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` and do this status polling there. But again, we would have to initialize this pool with at least 1 thread where runnable method to do the polling would run.

Any suggestions on why using `Thread.sleep` is said to be such a bad idea and what are the alternative options for achieving same as above.

http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2007/04/26/thread-sleep-is-a-sign-of-a-poorly-designed-program.aspx

Comment: http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2007/04/26/thread-sleep-is-a-sign-of-a-poorly-designed-program.aspx

Comment: Your link is about .Net. It doesn't apply to Java.

Comment: Polling is bad, no doubt. But if you don't have alternatives, it is the least thing you should care about.

Comment: @StinePike, Is that supposed to mean, Answer lies in the blog? I have gone through the post but didn't see any thing in particular apart from resource blocking (already mentioned) and this

`The thread needs perform logic every n milliseconds
As noted earlier, Sleep means relinquish control.  When your thread gets control again isn't up to the thread; so it can't be used for periodic logic.`

But I assume, he is talking about scheduling exactly after n milliseconds.

Comment: whoever voted as 'Too broad' please let me know how can I make it more specific? I have pretty much asked about use case of method in question.

Comment: Using `Thread.sleep()` is okay in certain situations (see accepted answer, for example). But you should never catch and ignore the `InterruptedException`!

Comment: so `Thread.sleep()` is okay to use if you want to sync notification/update from your API right?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It's fine to use `Thread.sleep` in that situation. The reason people discourage `Thread.sleep` is because it's frequently used in an ill attempt to fix a race condition, used where notification based synchronization is a much better choice etc.

In this case, AFAIK you don't have an option but poll because the API doesn't provide you with notifications. I can also see it's an infrequent operation because presumably you are not going to create thousand tables.

Therefore, I find it fine to use `Thread.sleep` here. As you said, spawning a separate thread when you are going to block the current thread anyways seems to complicate things without merit.

Comment: One big caveat: make sure that the sleeping thread isn't holding onto scarce resources, like a mutex or database connection.

Comment: Would this pattern be also acceptable in following case? -  Polling SQS for one message at a time and maintaining a list of messages. When size of list reaches X number, process them in bulk. If there are no more messages in SQS, sleep for some time. Again poll after that.

Comment: @Jitendra: Usually with MQs you'd want avoid polling, but AFAIK there is no other way than to poll in SQS (which by the way they charge for even when there is no message), so `Thread.sleep` is an option. I might be inclined to use scheduled executor though because it makes it easy to add consumers, finetune the scheduling of polling and forces you to separate business logic and infrastructure.

Answer (score 18):

Yes, one should try to avoid usage of Thread.sleep(x) but it shouldn't be totally forgotten:

Why it should be avoided

- It doesn't release the lock
- It doesn't gurantee that the execution will start after sleeping time (So it may keep waiting forever - **obviously a rare case**)
- If we mistakenly put a foreground processing thread on sleep then we wouldn't be able to close that application till x milliseconds.
- We now full loaded with new concurrency package for specific problems (like design patterns (**ofcourse not exactly**), why to use Thread.sleep(x) then.

Where to use Thread.sleep(x):

- For providing delays in background running threads
- And few others.

Comment: Can you explain few others? btw great answer.