# Selenium WebDriver C# Element not visible and unable to enter Data in Text Field

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

The URL of website is http://www.mca.gov.in/mcafoportal/viewCompanyMasterData.do
and when I click the Search icon beside Company/LLP Name it opens an overlay
with a text input to enter the company name, but the element is not visible in Selenium Webdriver C#
[Here's the Screenshot of the wepPage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmAtE.jpg)
Below is the HTML code for Text Field

```
<input type="text" size="40" id="searchcompanyname" name="searchcompanyname" onkeydown="javascript: if (event.keyCode==13) return fetchCINData();">
```

and here's my C# code

```
IWebDriver chrome = new ChromeDriver("C:\\");
        chrome.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.mca.gov.in/mcafoportal/viewCompanyMasterData.do");
        chrome.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='imgSearchIcon']")).Click();
        bool a = chrome.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[type=text][name='searchcompanyname']")).Displayed;
        MessageBox.Show(""+a,"");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click the search icon it takes +1 seconds for the form and the search input to get displayed, But in your code you're checking the element right after clicking the search icon which will take just a couple of milliseconds.
So you need to wait before doing that, maybe using `Thread.Sleep(2000);`
Or better keep checking if the element is displayed each -maybe- 500 ms.

Comment: `Thread.Sleep()` is [highly discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17826651/why-thread-sleep-is-bad-to-use)

You should be using explicit or implicit waits for these types of issues. 

`WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    IWebElement myDynamicElement = wait.Until<IWebElement>(d => d.FindElement(By.Id("someDynamicElement")));`

is an example. 

See the webdriver [documentation](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp)