# Posting Status in Facebook using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

How to Post Status in Facebook using Selenium and Java?I have tried below code which doesn't work.Able to login but getting error no such element while posting status.After login i am getting notification popup allow or block,how to handle this popup also? Below the code i am using for testing this.

```
public class NewTest {
private WebDriver driver;

 @Test
public void testEasy() throws InterruptedException {

driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
Thread.sleep(5000);
driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("email");
driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys("password" + Keys.ENTER);

Thread.sleep(5000);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//textarea[@title=\"What's on your mind?\"]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//textarea[@title=\"What's on your mind?\"]")).sendKeys("Hello World");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//textarea[@title=\"What's on your mind?\"]")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

}

@BeforeTest
public void beforeTest() {
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
    "C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\Test\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
driver = new ChromeDriver();
}

@AfterTest
public void afterTest() {
driver.quit();
}
```

}

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? Selenium is meant to test your code that you run locally, not manipulate some third parties code that runs elsewhere

Comment: You should use Facebook API instead

Answer (score 0):

1. Your XPath expression is not very correct, as far as I can see thte [title](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_title.asp) of the relevant [textarea](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp) looks like:

   ```
   What's on your mind, user1984
   ```

   so you need to amend your locator to use [XPath `contains()` function](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727) like:

   ```
   By.xpath("//textarea[contains(@title,\"What's on your mind\")]")
   ```
2. Using [Thread.sleep](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep-long-) is a [performance anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17826651/why-thread-sleep-is-bad-to-use), you should be using [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) instead. Example refactored code:

   ```
   driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("email"))).sendKeys("email");
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("pass"))).sendKeys("password" + Keys.ENTER);


   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//textarea[contains(@title,\"What's on your mind\")]"))).click();
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//textarea[contains(@title,\"What's on your mind\")]"))).sendKeys("Hello World");
   ```

Comment: Thanks.But i am getting same error when i tried above code.Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//textarea[contains(@title,"What's on your mind\")]"}