# Creating a pause or waiting effect in java program

Tags: java

I am writing a simple fishing simulator game in Java. I wanted there to be a randomly generated waiting time after each cast. When the wait was over, a random event would occur(a fish would be caught, a fish would steel your bait, etc). I have heard allot of bad things about Thread.sleep() and was wondering what would work best for me in this situation.

currently I am using something like this

```
Random random = new Random();
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
long difference = random.nextInt(9000);
boolean timeMet = false;

while(!timeMet){
   if((time + difference) <= System.currentTimeMillis())
      timeMet = true;
}

return event;
```

Comment: Sleeping would be better than busy waiting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider using a [SwingTimer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Check out this [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182223/is-there-any-better-or-alternative-way-to-skip-avoid-using-thread-sleep1000-in).

On the topic of whether Thread.sleep is bad or not, check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17826651/why-thread-sleep-is-bad-to-use-java).

Comment: Glad I could be of help, best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

What have you heard bad about `Thread.sleep(millis)`?  Using the cpu to keep busy for some period of time is quite wasteful.

Just use `Thread.sleep(difference);`

Comment: http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2007/04/26/thread-sleep-is-a-sign-of-a-poorly-designed-program.aspx   It's just one resource, but I was still worried. I wanted to get opinions from allot of people before deciding what to do

Comment: All of those examples have to do with Threading.  It doesn't look like you are using Threads, so ignore it.

Comment: Ya, I'm fairly new to Java and honestly have no clue what threading is.

Comment: Until you start using mulitple code streams that may run concurrently, you can just think of your code running in a single cpu core (a "thread").  In this case, Thread.sleep(millis), just specifies that you want your program to give up the cpu for a period of time and then have the OS return control to your program.

Comment: What about the Swing Timer?